# AWS - Possible to disable regions in interface?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm looking to see if it would be possible to filter/disable the regions in the interface of my IAM users ?

[image]

I just want to my users see this regions, it's possible ?

```
us-west-1   
us-west-2   
ap-southeast-1
ap-east-1
eu-west-1
eu-west-2
```

EDIT --

If not possible what do you think about my policy for my organization ?

```
{
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "Action": "*",
  "Resource": "*",
  "Condition": {
    "StringNotEquals": {
      "aws:RequestedRegion": [
        "us-west-1",
        "us-west-2",
        "eu-west-1",
        "eu-west-2",
        "ap-east-1",
        "ap-west-1",
        "ap-southeast-1"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not currently possible, but it sure would be a nice feature.

If you want to prevent your users from deploying resources into certain regions, it is possible to implement restrictions with IAM policies and Service Control Policies [1].

In addition, some of the newer regions are disabled by default, and if you want to enable them you have to opt in at the AWS account level.  However AFAIK it is not possible to disable any of the "enabled by default" regions [2].

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande-manage.html

Comment: Correct. According to the docs "Regions introduced prior to March 20, 2019 are all enabled by default and can’t be disabled."

[Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/accounts/latest/reference/manage-acct-regions.html)